# How can pass params along with fetch request in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, fetch

As i am doing an app in react native. Am i able to pass data along with fetch request? Also how to pass data from one page to another within `TouchableOpacity`?Following is my code..

**screenOne.js**

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenTwo', {course.term_id})}>
        {this.props.course.term_id == '28' ? (<Text></Text>) : (
         <Text style={styles.userStyle}>{this.props.course.name}
         </Text> )}
```

But above code is showing syntax error. Also i want this `term_id` to be passed along with fetch request.How can i do that?Can i do like the following?

**ScreenTwo.js**

```
fetch('https:/asdfcokn/lm-json/course + term_id')
```

Please do help..

Comment: I think you use wrong syntax, replace `{course.term_id}` by something like `{id: course.term_id}`. And you can get this in other screen in `navigationOptions`: `id: navigation.state.params.id`

Comment: Okay thank you i can i also access this `id` inside jsx ryt? `<Text>{id}</Text>` like this?

Comment: You can use through `navigation.state.params`

Comment: I've done like this `static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => { id: {navigation.state.params}; }` and inside jsx like this `<Text>{navigation.state.params.id}</Text>` but not working

Comment: `let {id} = this.props.navigation.state.params` and render `<Text>{id}</Text>`. Refer https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#StackNavigator